# Android M QRread error.. Error at opening camera

Tags: android, qr-code

I followed [this](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView/tree/master/QR-ReaderExample) to read QR Code..

Here I have integrated this in my application and its working fine since few days..

Its working fine with android 2 to 5.1 versions
till Api 22 its wokring fine....

But Now in android 6
Api 23 or more....

I am getting this error..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:511)
at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:353)
at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface.open(GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface.java:57)
at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.CameraManager.openDriver(CameraManager.java:77)
at com.my.qr.sdata.QRCodeReaderView.surfaceCreated(QRCodeReaderView.java:82)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:582)
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:177)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Can any one Help me on this at android 6... this is working fine in android 5 and 5.1 and android 2.3.3 also..

**Update**

Now I understand I need to Add Permissions in android 6 or higher..

Can any one suggest me where should I need to add or change my code from above error..

[this](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView/blob/master/QRCodeReaderView-lib/qrcodereaderview/src/main/java/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/QRCodeReaderView.java) is my representative code

https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView/blob/master/QRCodeReaderView-lib/qrcodereaderview/src/main/java/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/QRCodeReaderView.java

Please suggest me any one most of users waiting for android permissions in android 6 and new versions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added Run time permissions...

Like this :

At the part of Run time... I have added this at on create...

```
if (CheckPermission(this, Manifest.permission.Camera)) {
            YourStuffHandling();
        } else {
            RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.Camera, REQUEST_READ_PERMISSION );
        }
```

and over here My app will process..(QRcode..)

```
private void YourStuffHandling() {
}
```

and responding with this..

```
@Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

            switch (permsRequestCode) {

                case REQUEST_READ_PERMISSION: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        YourStuffHandling();
                    } else {
                        ShowToast(getString(R.string.permission_needed_sms));
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                    Permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                        Permission)) {
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                            new String[]{Permission},
                            Code);
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean CheckPermission(Context context, String Permission) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Now it works fine for me,... I have added same for all other permissions.... at Runtime...

Answer (score 0):

Check your sdk version if it is 23 than you have to get permission run time

Comment: Yes But this is not regarding permission ,,, my target sdk is 23 but.. if its regarding permission I need to get exception like "1xxx nor current process has android.permission..CAMERA" but I am getting different error .. Please suggest me sir..

Comment: @Don'tBenegative what's your target sdk for this?

Comment: My requirements minSdkVersion 15, targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: @Don'tBenegative change your target to 22 or less and check in android 6.0 will work

Comment: @Jack That's a temporary solution and frankly speaking is bad design. Shouldn't the new permission model be followed instead?

Comment: @AbdulFatir yes why not but i only want to check that when he change to lower it is working or not

Comment: @AbdulFatir i have give permission suggestion in my ans before yours answer

Comment: Thanks @AbdulFatir sir please Suggest me where should I need to Add Permissions at [this code](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView/blob/master/QRCodeReaderView-lib/qrcodereaderview/src/main/java/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/QRCodeReaderView.java)  Please suggest me sir...                                     Jack sir my Target  is 23 and more.. I need to change permissions... Please help me

Comment: @Don'tBenegative you have checked api level 22 or less? it is working or not?

Comment: yes sir its working fine... but I need this for 23 or more so that ... my application is huge I don't to worry about this QR in feature versions.....

Comment: @Don'tBenegative ok. Now you have to get runtime permission at your activity before creating QRCodeReaderView object

Comment: Before that I have a button page sir on click button its opens QRCodeReaderView on that what should I need to give... I will Update my button page also sir please suggest me sir.....

Comment: @Don'tBenegative on button click ask permission for camera and check result in onRequestPermissionsResult if user give permission successfully than redirect to  QRCodeReaderView  else display error dialog

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your API LEVEL >= 23. If that's the case (as in Android 6), you'll have to ask permission to access camera at runtime. Manifest permissions won't work.

Read [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en) on how to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Sir this is my code.. https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView/blob/master/QRCodeReaderView-lib/qrcodereaderview/src/main/java/com/dlazaro66/qrcodereaderview/QRCodeReaderView.java

Please suggest me any one most of users waiting for android permissions in android 6 and new versions...

Answer (score 0):

try : Write in your gradle.build targetSdkVersion 22
check:
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>